# Как починить "mapping values are not allowed in this context"

Tags: yml

У меня есть .yml код, при запуске команды `docker-compose up --build` у меня вылетает ошибка:
`yaml: line 6: mapping values are not allowed in this context`

Код ниже:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:13.1
      privileged: true
      ports:
        - 5432:5432
      environment:
        POSTGRES_USER: dante
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: dante123456
        POSTGRES_DB: drf
  adminer:
    image: adminer:4.7.8-standalone
      restart: always
      ports:
        - 8080:8080
      depends_on:
        - db
```

Answer (score 0):

"image" это скалярное отображение, у него не может быть собственных подпунктов. Вам стоит исправить на следующий код:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:13.1
    privileged: true
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: dante
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: dante123456
      POSTGRES_DB: drf
  adminer:
    image: adminer:4.7.8-standalone
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - db
```